# HAML Javascript double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I've got below code that I want to run in HAML but this seems to create error.

It seems though double quotes aren't working inside double quotes.

Is there a way to make this part working?

```
:javascript
    #{"
          var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                         .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                         .dialog({
                             autoOpen: false,
                             modal: true,
                             height: 625,
                             width: 500,
                             title: ""
                         });
          $dialog.dialog('open');
          " if browser.ie8?}
```

Comment: “It seems though double quotes aren't working inside double quotes” – of course they don’t, you need to escape them. How else would you determine the end of the quote?

Comment: @matt I tried backslash but it doesn't seem to be working. How would you escape in HAML javascript?

Comment: With a backslash :-) What error are you getting? Alternatively you could use the `%{...}` syntax instead of your outer quotes.